# Google+ login Javascript api fires callback before finishing loading

Tags: javascript

As mentioned in the Google+ api documentation I am trying to asynchronusly load Javascript API for Google login with the following code in the `<head`> section

`<script>
 window.___gcfg = {
  lang: "en-US",
  parsetags: "onload"
 }
</script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js?onload=activate_google" async defer></script>`

The call back API shows a button that is hidden until the api loads. But even after the callback fires the the api keeps loading. If I press the Login button before the loading finishes the google login window is briefly shown and then it closes again.

I need to know how I can wait for the API to load completely and executed before showing the custom login button. I would like to avoid polling.

Answer (score 0):

According to: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/cors#Loadingthestandaloneauthclient

You can call:

`gapi.load('auth', function() {
  // at this point gapi.auth is ready.
});`